# Como acessar uma variavel array codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho dificuldades em pegar valores dentro de uma variável array no codeigniter ajude-me entender como funciona isso de uma vez por todas
Fiz uma busca no banco de dados que é enviada para a view por uma array:
Controller

```
$dados= array(
'perfil' => $this->perfil->perfil($id)
);
```

Na view tenho os dados que veio do controller. 
Verifico minha variável $perfil com `var_dump($perfil)` e aparece isso:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[artigo_id] => 2
[artigo_titulo] => A volta de cristo
[artigo_imagem] => 8f5364fb6f5204224529ce3345073906.jpg
[artigo_autor] => Nativo Natan Melo
)
)
```

Como faço para pegar as informações do índice artigo_autor?
Tento acessar fazendo

```
$perfil->artigo_autor;
```

Mais da um erro :

> Trying to get property of non-object.

Como eu devo proceder?

Comment: Basta `$perfil[0]->artigo_autor`

Comment: Não tem como eu acessar tipo assim;
$perfil->artigo_autor ?

Comment: O retorno do metodo tem que ser `row`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601236/codeigniter-return-result-and-row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o método `$this->perfil->perfil($id)` deve retornar apenas um unico registros mude o retorno dele de `result()` ou `result_array()` para `row()` assim não é criado o indíce zero e é possível acessar direto as propriedades do objeto.

Exemplo mude:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
return $query->result();
```

Para:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
return $query->row();
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Documentação - row()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows)

Comment: Perfeito, nunca mais eu esqueço . Muito obrigado